# Codeigniter Custom Pagination Link

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

anyone can suggest me how i can customize codeigniter pagination link to be like below bootstrap div ?

```
 <div class="float-right">
              1-50/200
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
              </div>
              <!-- /.btn-group -->
            </div>
```

[Bootstrap Pagination Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXp5d.jpg)

my codeigniter code is

```
$config['first_link'] = '';

      $config['last_link'] = '';

      $config['next_link'] = ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>';

      $config['prev_link'] = ' <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>';
```

but it does not fit to the style

Answer (score 0):

By Codeigniter pagination documentation, from pagination config you need to specify what will be opening tag and closing tag. Right now you are using wrong config item for this usage.

```
// Opening tag
$config[‘next_tag_open’] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right">';

// Closing tag
$config[‘next_tag_close’] = '</i></button>';
```

And for previous button

```
// Opening tag
$config[‘prev_tag_open’] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left">';

// Closing tag
$config[‘prev_tag_close’] = '</i></button>';
```